# simple question on SVD

Tags: matlab, svd

I have an algorithm that outputs a vector 'v' for every iteration. With ever iteration the change in vector v will get smaller and smaller.

therefore my psuedo code should be

if vold-v < 0.001 end iteration

what is the right way to compare two vectors for this purpose?
I believe i have to use SVD but can someone please give a tiny background on SVD and how i should implement it?

Comment: Why not compare the length of the $v_{old}$ and $v$?  Should be cheaper than SVD.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Drew the length of the vectors dont change, the values of the vector keep getting updated, anyway this seems to work for me now -> change=norm(vgrid-vgridold,2)

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear - I was referring to the norm of the vector (which measures length) rather than the number of elements.  You've figured out the solution I was suggesting yourself though!

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical thought is to use
$$
\lVert v_{now} - v_{old} \rVert \lt \epsilon
$$

Now you must choose a norm. If your language is Fortran, the command `norm(v)` uses the Euclidean norm.

Next, choose a threshold. In Fortran, the command `epsilon` will provide the $\epsilon$ factor for the indicated real precision.